# Use php array to loop in TYPO3 flex type

Tags: typo3

I'm building an extension and I have a field of type `flex`. I have an array with extracted records from a TS config that I like to use as prefilled values for a field, which I also want to be editable in the TYPO3 admin. So I want them to be shown as textarea, however I don't know how to use the array in the flex items configuration.

```
'<T3DataStructure>
        <meta>
                <langDisable>1</langDisable>
        </meta>
        <sheets>
                <sDEF>
                        <ROOT>
                                <TCEforms>
                                        <sheetTitle>Title</sheetTitle>
                                </TCEforms>
                                <type>array</type>
                                <el>
                                        <pageSelector>
                                                <TCEforms>
                                                        <label>Something</label>
                                                        <config>
                                                                <type>text</type>
                                                                <items type="array">
                                                                        <numIndex index="0" type="array">
                                                                                <numIndex index="0">'.$php_variable_array.'</numIndex>
                                                                                <numIndex index="1">0</numIndex>
                                                                        </numIndex>
                                                                </items>
                                                                <minitems>0</minitems>
                                                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                                        </config>
                                                </TCEforms>
                                        </pageSelector>
                                </el>
                        </ROOT>
                </sDEF>
        </sheets>
</T3DataStructure>'
```

Comment: You should add a minimal example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using? Since TYPO3 8 LTS you can use "Field Wizards" to extend TCA types (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Rendering/Index.html#node-expansion). Thus, you can define the regular `text` form element and enrich this with a custom rendering of a drop-down selection - however, you have to implement that logic on your own. TCA type `text` does not have `items` per default (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text.html)